# WordPress wrong Redirect

Tags: wordpress

Something strange is happened, with my last wordpress migration site.

I`m updated all permalinks.

Update to my domain the 'home' and 'siteurl' in database, but my site redirects all pages to a url with '#'.

http://www.dnnsport.com/facts-news/

to

http://www.dnnsport.com/#/facts-news/

I don´t have any redirect activated.
I check all plugins.

Any idea, whats is probably happened?

Thanks a lot for any help, on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to this in the dashboard it you should be able to edit the url: https://cdn4.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/changesiteurls-adminarea.png

You also have the option to update your functions.php file like so:

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://example.com' );
```

Comment: Hi @Jonah,i`m already trying to fix, with your suggestion. But the problem is not from there. In database the ´'siteurl' and 'home' values are correct.

Comment: what is the format you're on under permalinks for new posts/pages? ex. http://example.com/sample-post/

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks? (you can do this by just pressing save on the permalinks settings page)

Comment: @Josh, yes i did!

Comment: @Jonah, is like your example - http://dnnsport.com/sample-post/